# Changing a class component to a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and am trying to learn how to change a class component I have into a functional component. The concept makes sense, but I am a little confused on how to do it with more than one state.

```
class PostListWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayCategory: "View All",
      posts: props.posts,
      postCategories: props.postCategories
    };
    this.setCategory = this.setCategory.bind(this);
  }
  setCategory(post_category) {
    this.setState({
      displayCategory: post_category
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <FilterSection setCategory={this.setCategory} state={this.state} posts={this.state.posts} />;
  }
}
```

So far I have

```
const PostListWrapper = () => {

  const [displayCategory, setDisplayCategory] = React.useState("View All");
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState(posts);
  const [postCategories, setPostCategories] = React.useState(postCategories);

  const setCategory = () => setDisplayCategory(postCategories);

    return (
      <FilterSection setCategory={this.setCategory} state={this.state} posts={this.state.posts} />
    );
}
```

I am just not sure how to handle `const setCategory = () => setDisplayCategory(postCategories);`

Comment: `post_category` was a parameter from the `FilterSection` in the class version, why not do the same thing in the function version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class version, the `post_category` is the argument passed to `setCategory` by the child component. In the functional component, you already have an updater function which updates the category state, the state dispatch function `setPostCategories`, so pass that down:

```
<FilterSection setCategory={setPostCategories}
```

You do not need to also declare the `setCategory` variable - you can remove it entirely.